# Why is acidic strength of A>B?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carboxylic-acids

a) H-(C=O)-OH

b) H-(C=O)-O-OH

The acidic strength of the two structures given below  was a>b .
I think the explanation to that is in structure A, the O atom of carboxyllic acid is in resonance with O anion therefore more stable thereby more acidic.
While in b the O anyone is not in resonance.
However why can't the O anyone br in lone pair lone par resonance with the previous oxygen atom which makes the chain complete there by making b more acidic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the resonance in the conjugate anion, the deprotonated oxygen atom has to share an electron pair with its neighbor and that extra shared pair then overlaps an antibonding orbitals to the rest of the molecule. So the resonance/delocalization has to weaken a bond in order to make the new one. With the anion of (A) the weakened bond is a $\pi$ bond, while in in the (B) anion we have to weaken a $\sigma$ bond which is a greater energy cost. While there are molecules where resonance/delocalization impacts $\sigma$ bonds, they are less common than those where weaker $\pi$ bonds are affected in this way.

WP indicates that the $pK_a$ for the peroxy acid B is about [7.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performic_acid), versus about [3.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formic_acid) for the "normal" acid A.

This effect is seen with methyl groups on the catboxyl carbon too. WP articles for the corresponding acetic acid species indicate that the $pK_a$ for the two acids is about [8.2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peracetic_acid) for the proxy acid versus about [4.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetic_acid) for the "normal" acid.